# restrict database table to contain unique data

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I am using hibernate in my project.

I have a `Team` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "team")
public class Team {
     private int tid; //primary key

     private int size;
     private String name;
     private boolean isNew;
     private String other;

     //Setter & Getter
     ...
}
```

Then, I created a `team` table in MySQL database with the following sql statement:

```
CREATE TABLE team (
    tid int not null auto_increment, 
    size int not null,
    name varchar(128),
    is_new bool default false,
    other varchar(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (tid)
) ENGINE innodb CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Each row of data in this table represents a `team` object.

How can I restrict this table to contain **unique team**? I mean how to ensure that there are **no** teams in the table have exactly the save value for every field(column)?

**NOTE:**  What I mean is not to have one column (one field) be unique, **but the row of data** be unique. That's to ensure there are no multiple teams have every field be the same.

For example the following 2 teams are unique & acceptable since their names are different:

```
Team 1: size = 3  name = "team1" isNew = true  other="nothing"
Team 2: size = 3  name = "team2" isNew = true  other="nothing"
```

For another example, the following 2 teams are exactly the same (no field has different value) which my table should NOT accept:

```
Team 1: size = 3  name = "team" isNew = true  other="nothing"
Team 2: size = 3  name = "team" isNew = true  other="nothing"
```

I mean in `team` table two teams could have the same value for multiple fields as long as there is **at least one field different**. Then, they are distinguishable unique teams.

Comment: See my answer `@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"tid", "size","name","is_new","other"})` this will take care of unique row each time

Comment: I mean in database table two teams could have the same value for multiple fields as long as there is at least one field different. Then, they are distinguishable teams. Does your answer fits my requirement?

Comment: `Does your answer fits my requirement?` Yes.

Comment: @leem.fn yes it does it will check for the unique row each time, emphasize on **unique row** not a single unique column

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, thanks, probably 'tid' shouldn't be included in your asnwer, since it is the primary key.

Comment: Making the team `name` unique would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a unique constraint for the columns you want the group to be unique in your entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "team",
uniqueConstraints= @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "size","name","is_new","other"}))
```

or for each column

```
@Entity
@Table(name="team") 
public class Team{
.
.
.
  @Column(name = "size", unique=true)
  private String size;
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a UNIQUE constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE team (
    tid int not null auto_increment, 
    size int not null,
    name varchar(128),
    is_new bool default false,
    other varchar(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (tid),
    CONSTRAINT uc_Name UNIQUE (size,name,is_new,other)
) ENGINE innodb CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

That ensures each team must have all columns unique

Comment: What I mean is not to have one column be unique, but the row of data. That's to ensure there are no multiple teams have every field be the same.

Comment: Ok, add all columns to the Constraint. I edited my anwser. But I think that would be enough for the team to be different, if the name be unique